# What is more efficient code than the code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Below is the code to get the Topaz ObjectContainer in brick or tile.

```
    public static ITopazObjectContainer GetTopazObjectContainer(Transform t)
    {
        ITopazObjectContainer i = (t.GetComponent<Tile>() as ITopazObjectContainer);

        if (i == null)
            i = (t.GetComponent<Brick>() as ITopazObjectContainer);

        return i;
    }
```

What is more efficient code than the code?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [codereview.se]?

Comment: I don't know Unity that well, so I don't know if it will work or not, but would just `{ return t.GetComponent<ITopazObjectContainer>(); }` work?

Comment: no, `.GetComponent` only retrieves classes derived from `Component` attached to the current game object

Comment: Alternatively, here's an idea of how you might use the non-generic version of `GetComponent()` to grab an interface directly: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/43960/how-to-get-the-first-component-that-implements-a-s.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetComponent<Interface>()` has been supported since Unity 4.6 ([release notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-4.6))

I tested the below code in Unity 5.3.4f1 just to be sure it wasn't removed. (It's been a while since I did it before).

So:

```
public static ITopazObjectContainer GetTopazObjectContainer(Transform t)
{
     return t.GetComponent<ITopazObjectContainer>();
}
```

Better yet would be to cache that reference, if you have to call it multiple times. Not sure how the rest of your code is designed though.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (t.GetComponent<Tile>() as ITopazObjectContainer) ?? (t.GetComponent<Brick>() as ITopazObjectContainer);
```

Comment: well, your not using the extra memory to cache the variable

Comment: Ew. Not more-efficient-enough to be worth making it unreadable.

Comment: Anybody reading it. Long lines with ternaries are generally unpleasant.

Comment: this would get my vote. Maybe break it into a few lines for readability.

Comment: @DaveNewton its not a ternary though, its just a single null coalesce

Comment: Fair enough. As a single line I still think it's hard to read.